# Connect two fpga through the usb protocol

Tags: usb, fpga

I want to get information about the connection of two fpga via usb,But I only found information about usb drive and the connection of two fpga to other methods like spi etc ...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Then, rephrase your question to be more specific on what are yout trying to achieve, so you will have more chance of getting quality answers.

Comment: 4. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The USB protocol is rather complex. Theoretical you could put it in an FPGA but it would become very, very big. It is more efficient to add a processor, either internal or external to the FPGA to run the protocol.

Look for FPGAs with embedded processor. They often come with built-in USB, Ethernet and DDR controller.

Comment: I know. But I do not know what to use usb...for example usb 2.0 or usb host core?

Comment: From that question I assess that your knowledge of USB is far from the level required . I strongly suggest you study USB and the protocol and the standard a lot more. Otherwise you attempt is likely to fail or you will need to ask a hundred more questions here to get it to work.